# How do I draw other circle to the right instead of under?

Tags: latex

I have this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    mycirc/.pic={
        \foreach \w in {0,0.5} {
            \draw (0,\w) circle (0.5cm);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (2,2) {mycirc};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code draws to circles intersecting. I want the circles to intersect from the right instead of from under. How do I do it?

Comment: better if you ask it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    mycirc/.pic={
        \foreach \w in {0,0.5} {
            \draw (\w,0) circle (0.5cm);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (2,2) {mycirc};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```